# SQL 2005 Reporting Services doesn't print properly

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

We have a 900+ page report that was created in RS.  You can only print 1 page at a time from the report manager.  We have tried exporting to pdf, etc but the dollar amounts don't line up properly when it is exported.  Does anyone have any suggestions to get this to print correctly?

Comment: Have you tried exporting to excel?  What is not lining up?  Totals?  Amounts from page to page?

Comment: Yea that didn't work - it didn't keep the "pretty" format we set up.  These are donor reports that need to look top notch.  There are a series of account balances on the report and the totals don't line up by decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure all the page sizes, breaks, margins, interactive size, etc. are properly setup for the export to work properly. You also should be able to print the whole thing in one go from the report manager in 2005.

Do your other reports print ok?

Do you have conditional filters, hidden contorls, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you use table and right-align your dollar amount column it should line up properly.

Can you provide more details like what kind of report layout you are using ( which objects you are using to render report. )